# React Native throw null is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem understanding why this code isnt working.
If i use it like this:

```
   const [theInfo , setTheInfo] = useState(null);

    return (
              theInfo ?(
              ...):(
              ...)
```

Its working without any problems. But as soon as i add a View or anything above or after `theInfo...` like this:

```
  const [theInfo , setTheInfo] = useState(null);
return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>Hi</Text>
      </View>
      theInfo ?(
      ...):(
      ...)
     </View>
```

Then I get this error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'theInfo.map')
I dont understand why this is happening. I want to set a searchbar on top, and after this the `theInfo?(...` part

Answer (score 1):

theInfo is a variable, you can't use it jsx in such a way, inclose it in curly braces :

```
  const [theInfo , setTheInfo] = useState(null);
 return (
<View>
  <View>
    <Text>Hi</Text>
  </View>
 {
  theInfo ?(
  ...):(
  ...)
  }
 </View>
```